# The test of the bread from heaven

Tags: commentaries, beshalach, ekev, mon-manna, test

The verse of Shemot 16:4 tells that HaShem will cause bread to rain (come down) from heaven to (humble; Devarim 8:16 and) test the people whether or not they will walk in His Torah.

The literal rendering of a part of this verse is that the people had to gather a word a day in its day.

Devarim 8:3 refers to this and tells that HaShem did so in order to teach that we don't live by bread alone, but by all (words) that comes forth from the mouth of HaShem.

The text shows the way HaShem tested the people (by gathering the Mahn), and its goal (to see if they would walk in His Torah); but how where the people tested by this act, and in which way did the gathering of Mahn represents the goal or that which was tested?

Comment: I don't understand what your second paragraph is doing in the question. What does it add to the question?

Comment: @msh210 I think he is looking for a hint to its meaning in a parallel verse.

Comment: Gather a word and walking in His torah are sayings.. walking in Torah substains us, but what does the gathering of a word do for us? The Word of HaShem and Torah are often synonym.  Maybe he is looking for any connection or any link between these sayings ore to the literal deed of gathering manna?

Answer (score 1):

The Rashbam translates לנסותכם as bothering. Hashem put them through the grind. They never had physical insurance of food for the next day, and they had to collect an exact amount. People usually don't appreciate war time rations. This was to see if they'll follow, and trust in, Hashem.